# Applying regex replace for text inside elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have elements like this all over the page:

```
<span class="am-product-terms">$49.95 for each 3 months</span>
<span class="am-product-terms">$149.95 for each year</span>
```

I wanted to remove the the `for...` part all up to the end. So I did this:

```
$('.am-product-terms').replace(/for[\s\S]+/, '')
```

That threw an error so I tried this:

```
$('.am-product-terms').text().replace(/for[\s\S]+/, '')
```

This didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.replace()` returns modified string it doesn't update existing text. You need to use returned string and reset it to inputs text.

You can use [`.text(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)

```
$('.am-product-terms').text(function(_, text){
    return text.replace(/for[\s\S]+/, '');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the first time I see this. Why the need to `return` and not in normal cases?

Comment: @alexchenco `.replace() returns modified string it doesn't update existing text.`

Comment: So by adding `return` the existing one is being `returned`?

Comment: @alexchenco, only `return` is added, I have use overloaded `.text()` function to set replaced string.